# Premiere Pro - auto update adjustment layers

Tags: premiere-pro, adjustment-layers

I have an adjustment layer in my project:

[image: POV adjustment layer, tan]

Which you can see has three instances in my timeline on top of the same shot type (so all will want the same colour correction to match exactly)

[image: POV adjustment layer in three instances above three shots in a timeline]

And as far as I can see, when dragging the adjustment layer in to my timeline this will always have its own properties on each of these three timeline instances (i.e. I can change each adjustment layer separately like the warmth and the other instances of POV will keep their own (old) warmth values)

I'm new to Premiere Pro, but I assumed that creating an adjustment layer would be smarter and each adjustment layer would maintain its changes so I can update one and see these updates automatically in my timeline - again as an example, if I update the warmth of the first POV adjustment layer, then the other two would auto update.

This doesn't seem to be the case, so I'm wondering if there is a way to do this so I can change one adjustment layer and have its brother instances auto update so I can quickly and efficiently colour correct multiple shots in my timeline.

The only ideas I had was:

1. to embed the adjustment layer in to a sequence and reuse that sequence three times, so opening one changes the embedded layer, but PP doesn't seem to want me to drag in the sequence, and instead inserts the adjustment layer in to the timeline.
2. putting the adjustment layer in to a nested sequence seems to fix this but then I have the problem of the nested layer sitting above my footage causing it to just black out any layers below it